# Expressing thermal efficiency for a closed Brayton cycle in terms of static enthalpies

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine

I have a [Brayton cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brayton_cycle) made of a compressor (stage 2 to 3), a heat exchanger (stage 3 to 4) and a turbine (stage 4 to 5). The turbine and compressor are connected through a shaft. The cycle is closed via a heat exchanger, where the hot recirculating air is cooled. Here is an image:

[image: diagram of a Brayton cycle]

The book from which this image was taken ([*Fundamentals of Propulsion, by Ronald D. Flack*](http://www.cambridge.org/ru/academic/subjects/engineering/aerospace-engineering/fundamentals-jet-propulsion-applications)) defines an important coefficient, called the thermodynamic efficiency, given by:
$$\eta_{th}=\dfrac{\dot{W}_{net}}{\dot{Q}_{in}}$$
Right after defining this coefficient, the author says that for the ideal case this is equal to:
$$\eta_{th}=1-\dfrac{h^{\prime}_5-h_2}{h_4-h^{\prime}_3}$$
where, as he says, "the primes (') serve as reminders that the processes are ideal".

**How did he get to that last expression, using enthalpies?**

I tried using the general expression for the conservation of energy for a (stationary) control volume (CV):
$$0=\dot{Q}_\text{CV}-\dot{W}_\text{CV}+\dot{m}_\text{in}\left(h_\text{in}+\frac{v_\text{in}^2}{2}\right)-\dot{m}_\text{out}\left(h_\text{out}+\frac{v_\text{out}^2}{2}\right)$$
where:

- $\dot{Q}_\text{CV}$ is the heat transfer rate over the boundary of the CV.
- $\dot{W}_\text{cv}$ is the energy transfer by work across the boundary of the control volume.

I can apply this formula to the compressor, for example, and I'd get the following:
$$\dot{W}_{c}=\dot{m}\left(h_{02}-h_{03}\right)$$

But all in all, I don't know how to express the thermal efficiency in terms of *static enthalpies*, as using my approach all I'd get would be *stagnation enthalpies*.

Comment: Hi Jose - we tend to prefer that questions ask something specific. If all you can say is "I don't know how to continue", that's not really _asking_ anything. Could you consider whether you can focus on a more specific aspect? That being said, this question is not too bad, relatively speaking.

Comment: Hey @DavidZ thanks for your insights. Inside the "Question" block I formulated the question, which is: "how did he get to that last expression, using enthalpies?". Anyway I made it clearer at the end of the "My Attempt" block and deleted that "I don't know how to continue" part. I know there are some mathematical operations behind, and that's my specific question. Does this work or not yet? Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah, that's somewhat better. Like I said, it's not really a bad question. I think your formatting (e.g. the section headings) might be getting in the way of readability a _bit_. If you like, I could make some slight edits to improve that.

Comment: Hey @DavidZ, please go ahead and help me with the formatting. Would be great!

Comment: All done, take a look and make sure everything looks OK. The changes are minor but I think they help focus on the real question.

Comment: Everything is correct @DavidZ, thanks for making it clearer. Now I need to sit and wait for some answers to come in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check first law for compressor, turbine and high temperature heat exchanger.

If compressor and turbine are ideal, then we have:

First law for compressor: $w_c=h_2-h'_3$

First law for high temperature heat exchanger: $q_{in}=h_4-h'_3$

First law for turbine: $w_t=h_4-h'_5$

$$\large{\eta_{th}}=\large{\frac{w_{net}}{q_{in}}}$$

$w_{net}=w_t+w_c=h_4-h'_5+h_2-h'_3=(h_4-h'_3)-(h'_5-h_2)$

$$\Longrightarrow\;\large{\eta_{th}}=\large{\frac{(h_4-h'_3)-(h'_5-h_2)}{h_4-h'_3}}=1-\large{\frac{h'_5-h_2}{h_4-h'_3}}$$